# How to find out if all my Hardware is supported on Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers

As asked above: How can I find out if my current hardware in the computer is supported on Linux?

Comment: wow I dont understand, what did I wrong?

Comment: We don't know your hardware specs. Which Linux are you wanting to try? There are many flavours. There are x64 and x32 types. We cannot see your computer. Please update your question with your computer specs, model, memory in gigabytes, hard drive size, et cetera.